# Powershel sum timespan

Tags: powershell

How can i some this two timespan?

```
$Result1 = ($DurationVideo | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Sum).Sum
$mts =  [timespan]::FromMilliseconds($Result1)
$VideoTime =("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $mts)
[pscustomobject]@{'Timespan' = $VideoTime}


$Result2 = ($DurationAudio | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Sum).Sum
$Nts =  [timespan]::FromMilliseconds($Result2)
$AudioTime =("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $Nts)
[pscustomobject]@{'Timespan' = $AudioTime}
```

Output:

```
  Timespan    
  --------    
  00:10:28,631
  03:55:10,000
```

I need:

```
 04:05:38,631
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: just add them - PoSh can do timespan math. like this >>> `([timespan]'00:10:28.631' + [timespan]'03:55:10.000).ToString()' <<< the output is `04:05:38.6310000`

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks a lot! However this is a know values, but i need to sum unknown values. Values that a get in a lot of objects, the gives-me thet output. On this case i get  00:10:28,631
  03:55:10,000, but could be some other.

Comment: I figure it out! ([timespan]$Nts + [timespan]$mts).ToString().

Comment: `$durationvideo + $durationaudio`

Comment: Thanks js2010, Works fine

Comment: @Paulo - i see that you used variables. that was implied by what i showed ... glad that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

The original variables look like timespan's to me:

```
$durationvideo + $durationaudio
```

You would think you could sum it with measure-object, but alas you can't:

```
[timespan]'1',[timespan]'1' | measure -sum  # two days

Measure-Object: Input object "1.00:00:00" is not numeric.
Measure-Object: Input object "1.00:00:00" is not numeric.
```